# Swift How to sort cells alphabetically by value in tableview

Tags: swift

I am building a RSS Reader. I want to sort cells alphabetically by value (“title”) in tableview. I tried something to solve my problem, but I didnt find any solution then I read different resource, but I didn't find any resource about RSS. How can I sort cells alphabetically by value (“title”) in tableview?

Here is my codes:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, XMLParserDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var parser = XMLParser()
var post = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()
var title1 = NSMutableString()
var textLink = NSMutableString()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    parsingDataFromUrl()
}

func parsingDataFromUrl() {
    post = []
    parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: NSURL(string: "feedRssLinkHere")! as URL)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    element = elementName as NSString
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqual(to: "item") {
        elements = NSMutableDictionary()
        elements = [:]
        title1 = NSMutableString()
        title1 = ""
        textLink = NSMutableString()
        textLink = ""
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    if element.isEqual(to: "title") {
        title1.append(string)
    } else if element.isEqual(to: "link") {
        textLink.append(string)
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqual(to: "item") {
        if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
            elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title" as NSCopying)
        }
        if !textLink.isEqual(nil) {
            elements.setObject(textLink, forKey: "link" as NSCopying)
        }
        post.add(elements)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return post.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell

    if cell.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)! [0] as! MainCell
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = (post.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "title") as! NSString as String
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let titleLink = (post.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "link") as! NSString as String

    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: titleLink)!)
    present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: Please **do not use NSMutable... types in Swift at all**

Comment: What is your suggestion?

Comment: `String`, `[String]`, `[String:Any]`. You get mutability for free with the `var` keyword.

Answer (score -1):

After you parse the xml, sort the posts array before reloading the tableview.

then do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell

    if cell.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)! [0] as! MainCell
    }

let item = posts[indexPath.row]

    cell.titleLabel.text = item.value(forKey: "title") as! NSString as String
    return cell
}
```